# dcast 2 columns

Tags: r

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
group <- sample(c("egyptian", "american", "irish", "australian"), 50, TRUE)
E <- c(rnorm(50, 5, 6))
F <- c(rnorm(50, 7.8, 4.5))
G <- c(rnorm(50, 65, 16.7))
test <- data.frame(group=group, E=E, F=F, G=G)
```

My goal is to generate a `data.frame` that includes `group` as a header and lists its corresponding values in `E` below.

something like this `data.frame`:

```
egyptian <- c(rnorm(50,5,6))
american<- c(rnorm(50,5,6))
irish<- c(rnorm(50,5,6))
australian<- c(rnorm(50,5,6)) 
test <- data.frame(egyptian=egyptian, american=american, 
                   irish=irish, australian=australian)
```

I tried to subset the 2 columns and then use `dcast,` but it failed. 
Is it possible to `dcast` 2 columns from long to wide?

Comment: Just a heads up - to format code blocks, highlight all the relevant lines and either click the code button (pair of curly braces) or press `Ctrl`+`k` (presumably `command`+`k` on Mac), or alternatively manually indent each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: Also, please include an example of your desired output.

Comment: Because your groups are different sizes, you might also consider `split(test$E, test$group)`.

Comment: @jbaums , what you mean different size. all of them are 50

Comment: See my first comment... it looks like you are putting the cursor on each line of code in turn and clicking the code formatting button. You need to _highlight the entire block of code_. I'm going to roll back your edit and add your additional info.

Comment: ^^ No, `sample(c("egyptian", "american", "irish", "australian"), 50, TRUE)` does not create a vector with 50 of each of `egyptian`, `american`, `irish` and `australian`. It takes a random sample of these, of length 50, with replacement. Take a look at `test` for yourself. It's best if your example output corresponds to your example input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jbaums mentioned in the comments, the size of each group is not the same.

```
  table(test$group)
  # american australian   egyptian      irish 
  #   7         18          9         16
```

It is also better to set a seed to make it reproducible. i.e.

```
  set.seed(1)
  group <- sample(c("egyptian", "american", ....)
```

To transform initial input to the expected output (based on the "E" column), we may need to create a sequence based on the grouping variable ("group")

```
library(reshape2) 
test$ind <- with(test, ave(seq_along(group), group, FUN=seq_along))
dcast(test, ind~group, value.var='E')
```

Or another `base R` option would be to use `xtabs`

```
xtabs(E~ind+group, test)
```

But, note that this will pad '0' for those missing value combinations. For `dcast`, by default, we will get "NA" for the missing combinations, which we can change by `fill` argument.